# HTML select element doesn't show updated selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html select element inside of a td:

```
<td colspan="2" id="myOriginalTd">S: 
    <select class="inpDate">
        <option selected="selected" value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
                     .
                     .
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

If I copy the select element from one td to another -

```
$("#myOriginalTd").html(
    $("#myNewTd").html()
);
```

it displays with the original values the select element had when the page loaded.
I would like (the user) to change the value in the select element, then copy the element to a new td when a button is clicked having it display the newly selected value.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and the best way to do something like this?

Thanks!

edit: thanks for the responses!  I will look at them.  here is a link to jsfiddle - 
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/648ev2pf/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?  Should that copy happen on an event, such as when the select value changes or a button is clicked?

Comment: What do you want to change the selected value too? As you are copying the `html` to a new element the `selected` attribute is being copied too, as expected. DO you only want to change the selected value in the new element or in the original element too?

Comment: Hi Jon - the user changes the value, but looking at firebug, the selected attribute doesn't change.  When the html is copied, it has the original value selected.

Answer (score 2):

First, give your select an ID ("I'll assume selectToCopy)

```
$("#myNewTd").children("input[type=select]").val($("#selectToCopy").val());
```

Comment: Will this work?  Aren't you grabbing the .val() of the td element, when you need to grab it of the select.  Still, the principle looks right if you amend the jquery selector.

Comment: I misread IDs, thought those were input IDs...Edited code should work.

Comment: I think just $("#myNewTd .inpDate").val($("#myOriginalTd .inpDate").val()) would be easier?

Comment: Yes, that would be easier - I just try to use IDs and types since they're more specific than classes, but in this case it's irrelevant since it appears he only has one control inside that table cell, so you're definitely right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $("#myNewTd").replaceWith($("#myOriginalTd").clone(true, true));
```

Comment: +1 for clone, no need to read/write values and potentially reattach handlers.

Comment: This clones the `selected` attribute from the "donor". Whic misses the " I would like to change the value in the select element, then copy the element to a new td. " part of the question.